# simplifying summations

Tags: summation, systems-of-equations

From knowing

$7c=\sum_{i=1}^{50-c}k_i$

and

$c\choose 2 $=$  \sum_{i=1}^{50-c}$ $k_i\choose 2 $

how can I get to

$\sum_{i=1}^{50-c}(k_i-\mu)^2=(50-c)\mu^2-14c\mu+c^2+6c$

for some arbitrary $\mu$?

I would show you the many attempts I have made at this but I am sure it will look like gibberish. This is not homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did all that ugly derivations for you.

Let $n = 50 - c$.

Assume:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i = 7c$$

$${c\choose 2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} {k_i\choose 2}$$

Obtain:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (k_i - \mu)^2 = n\mu^2 - 14c\mu + c^2 + 6c$$

Proof.

(It looks like a variance.)

$$(k_i - \mu)^2 = k_i^2 - 2k_i\mu + \mu^2$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (k_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i^2 - 2k_i\mu + \mu^2$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (k_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i=1}^n k_i + \mu^2 \sum_{i=1}^n 1$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (k_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i=1}^n k_i + \mu^2 n$$

Then

$${k_i\choose 2} = \frac {(k_i - 1) k_i} 2$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} {k_i\choose 2}
 = \frac 1 2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i\right)
 = \frac {(c - 1)c} 2$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i = (c - 1)c$$

And substitute it all together

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (k_i - \mu)^2 = (c - 1)c + \sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i - 2\mu \sum_{i=1}^n k_i + \mu^2 n$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (k_i - \mu)^2 = (c - 1)c + 7c - 2\mu 7c + \mu^2 n$$

Comment: See also the source on how to typeset it properly.